# Mysql Syntax error when using prepared statement

Tags: mysql

I am creating a stored procedure which will be executing a prepared statement but on the creation the procedure I get mysql syntax error :

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'PREPARE udpatestatut FROM @req; EXECUTE
>   updatestatut; DEALLOCATE PREPARE upd' at line 4

I don't see what my mistake is so I need help to understand what I am doing wrong or writting wrong. Here down is the instructions I am executing.

CREATE PROCEDURE `changestatut`(IN `pstatut` VARCHAR(10), IN `pidpost` VARCHAR(255))

```
COMMENT 'This procedure change the statut of activities.' NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 

SET @req := concat('UPDATE compte set statut=\'', pstatut ,'\' where idpost in (', pidpost ,')'); 

PREPARE udpatestatut FROM @req; EXECUTE updatestatut; DEALLOCATE PREPARE updatestatut;
```

idpost parameter is a comma separated value ...e.g: 1,2,3,6

Comment: could you post sample value in `pidpost `

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple statements in your procedure you need to wrap them in a begin..end you might also be not setting delimiters. Try this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS changestatut;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE changestatut(IN pstatut VARCHAR(10), IN pidpost VARCHAR(255))

COMMENT 'This procedure change the statut of activities.' NOT DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
SET @req := concat('UPDATE compte set statut=\'', pstatut ,'\' where idpost in (', pidpost ,')'); 

PREPARE udpatestatut FROM @req; EXECUTE updatestatut; 

DEALLOCATE PREPARE updatestatut;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```